# can't make a python project into an executable because path issues?

Tags: python-3.x, module, pyinstaller

I'm trying to turn my python project into .exe

I used : `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

Then I moved the `main.exe` into the original file to be sure it can access all the dependencies.

When I run the `main.exe`, I get an error, `failed to execute script main`.

I typed cmd in the directory of the python project, and tried `python main.py`

It gave me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Even though every module are installed, why is it telling me that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed pyqt5.

Try `pip install pyqt5 or pip3 install pyqt5`

for linux

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: if you are using linux based os you can simply run sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 to install it